# Pygame: Snap-to-grid/board in chess

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pygame

Is there a way in pygame for sprites, when dragged, to snap to an invisible (or visible) grid? Kinda like drag 'n drop? If so, how? I've been trying to do some sprite overlap, but it's too tedious to make an if-statement for each of the grid-lines. So how can I make a snap-to-grid drag-n-drop sprite? This is for a chess program. I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't make an if statement for each line, use math, and loops. Lines are evenly spaced, they are all multiples of one space apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of corners of the chess board using for loops.

```py
corners = []
for x in range(edgeRight, edgeLeft, interval):
  for y in range(edgeTop, edgeBottom, interval):
    corners.append((x,y))
```

Then, make an event listener. When the piece is being dragged around, insert this code into whatever `while` statement you have:

```py
px, py = Piece.Rect.topleft //using tuples to assign multiple vars
for cx, cy in corners:
  if math.hypot(cx-px, cy-py) < distToSnap:
    Piece.setPos((cx,cy))
    break
```

I have no idea what your actual code is, but this should give you an idea. Again, `pygame` has no snap-to-grid functionality.

Comment: please clarify `edgeRight`, `edgeLeft`, `edgeTop`, `edgeBottom`.

Comment: Sorry. Those are the edges of the chess board area in pixels. So `edgeTop` is the pixel line where the top of the 8th rank starts (like 30) and `edgeLeft` is the a file (40) and so on.

Answer (score 2):

So this can be done quite simply by using the round function in python.

```
sprite.rect.x = ((round(sprite.rect.x/gridSquareSize))*gridSquareSize)
sprite.rect.y = ((round(sprite.rect.y/gridSquareSize))*gridSquareSize)
```

This manipulates the round function, by rounding your sprite's coordinates to the nearest grid square.